# What does HS in ski-jumping means?

Tags: trivia, skiing

[This is the ski-jumping calendar](http://www.fis-ski.com/ski-jumping/events-and-places/calendar/?sector=JP&season=2017&discipline=ALL&gender=M&start=2017-02-01) for men competitions in february 2017.

Is it possible to view several type of competitions:

- HS225
- HS140
- HS134
- HS130
- HS100

What does those abbreviations means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HS - [Hill Size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_size).

The numbers mean:

- 225 - ski flying hill
- 130, 134, 140 - large hill
- 100 - normal hill

There are also small and medium hills.

In the [international competition rules of ski jumping](http://www.fis-ski.com/mm/Document/documentlibrary/Skijumping/03/19/96/ICRSkiJumping2016_clean_English.pdf), on page 47, they define "hill size" as:

> HS the measured distance (Hill Size) from the edge to the takeoff to
>   the end of the landing area